# NInject: Sharing a constructor declaration across multiple bindings

Tags: c#, ninject

The objective is to avoid having to declare the same constructor arguments multiple times when configuring a kernel in the following manner:

```
Kernel.Bind<ISomeService>().To<SomeService>()
  .WithConstructorArgument("arg", "value");
Kernel.Bind<SomeService>.ToSelf()
  .WithConstructorArgument("arg", "value");
```

tried with:

```
Kernel.Bind<ISomeService>().To<SomeService>();
Kernel.Bind<SomeService>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("arg", "value");
```

Hoping that the "bind chain" will be taken into account, but nope.

Answer (score 1):

You can pack your argument in a type, for example:

```
public class FooConfig
{
    private readonly string value;

    public FooConfig(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Value
    { 
        get { return this.value; }
    }
}
```

then bind it like:

```
Bind<FooConfig>().ToConstant(new FooConfig("configValue"));
```

and then adapt the dependencies to have the `FooConfig` type injected.

Comment: Please do you think you could take at look a this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198294/how-to-configure-ninject-so-that-it-creates-a-single-instance-per-controller?noredirect=1#comment67673663_40198294